# выбрать все последнии значения по уникальному полю mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

есть таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в первом столбце всего 17 уникальных значений. Всего таких записей очень много. В первом столбце значения повторяются.  Как можно вывести по каждому значению из  первого столбца , его последнее значение из 2 столбца одним запросом?
У каждой записи есть столбец id(уникальный).

Comment: *его последнее значение* А что такое "последнее" значение? таблица - это несортированная куча, и в ней нет никаких первых-последних, пока не указана сортировка. Но в показанных данных нет ничего, по чему можно было бы сортировать, устанавливая относительный порядок записей с равным значением первого столбца. Так что задача нерешаема.

Comment: @Akina извиняюсь, у каждой записи есть свое id . От 1 до n .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM table t1
JOIN ( SELECT t2.col1, MAX(t2.id) id
       FROM table t2
       GROUP BY t2.col1 ) t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
                            AND t1.col1 = t3.col1
```

Comment: а что такое t2? у меня же всего 1 таблица

Comment: @Вадим Почитайте справку по термину "alias".